# Adding color gradient to material PointsMaterial in Three.js doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, three.js

Trying to add a color gradient to a simple spiral galaxy doesn't change how it's seen.

My code:

```
// Geometry
let geometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().setFromPoints(points)

// Loading a custom texture
// const texture = new
// THREE.TextureLoader().load('./star.png')
// const loadedTexture = new THREE.PointsMaterial({ map:texture })

// Creating a shader
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
      color1: {
        value: new THREE.Color("red")
      },
      color2: {
        value: new THREE.Color("purple")
      }
    },
    vertexShader: `
      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
      }
    `,
    fragmentShader: `
      uniform vec3 color1;
      uniform vec3 color2;

      varying vec2 vUv;

      void main() {

        gl_FragColor = vec4(mix(color1, color2, vUv.y), 1.0);
      }
    `
  });

const spiralGalaxy = new THREE.Points(geometry, new THREE.PointsMaterial(), material)
scene.add(spiralGalaxy)
```

I hoped to get a nice color gradient, but instead the color stays white. Setting the color directly in PointsMaterial does work. By some reason the shader doesn't get added to the Points mesh.

Comment: It won't work because: 1) `Points` constructor takes only two parameters, 2) you create a geometry from points, but you don't set `uv` attribute, so you won't be able to use it in shaders.